# Can I restore data from mongo oplog?

Tags: mongodb, backup, database-restore

my mongodb was hacked today, all data was deleted, and hacker requires some amount to get it back, I will not pay him, cause I know he will not send me back my database.

But I have had oplog turn on, I see it contains over 300 000 documents, saving all operations.

**Is there any tool that can restore my data from this logs?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on how far back your oplog is, you may be able to restore the deployment. I would recommend taking a backup of the current state of your `dbpath` just in case.

Note that there are many variables in play for doing a restore like this, so success is never a guarantee. It can be done using `mongodump` and `mongorestore`, but only if your oplog goes back to the beginning of time (i.e. when the deployment was first created). If it does, you *may* be able to restore your data. If it does not, you'll see errors during the process.

1. **Secure your deployment** before doing anything else. This situation arises due to a lack of security. There are extensive security features available in MongoDB. Check out the [Security Checklist page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) for details.
2. **Dump the oplog collection** using `mongodump --host <old_host> --username <user> --password <pwd> -d local -c oplog.rs -o oplogDump`.
3. **Check the content of the oplog** to determine the timestamp when the offending drop operation occur by using `bsondump oplogDump/local/oplog.rs.bson`. You're looking for a line that looks approximately like this:

   `{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1502172266,"i":1}},"t":{"$numberLong":"1"},"h":{"$numberLong":"7041819298365940282"},"v":2,"op":"c","ns":"test.$cmd","o":{"dropDatabase":1}}`

   This line means that a `dropDatabase()` command was executed on the `test` database.

   Keep note of the `t` value in `{"$timestamp":{"t":1502172266,"i":1}}`.
4. **Restore to a secure new deployment** using `mongorestore --host <new_host> --username <user> --password <pwd> --oplogReplay --oplogLimit=1502172266 --oplogFile=oplogDump/local/oplog.rs.bson oplogDump`

   Note the parameter to `oplogLimit`, which is basically telling `mongorestore` to stop replaying the oplog once it hit that timestamp (which is the timestamp of the `dropDatabase` command in Step 3.

   The `oplogFile` parameter is new to MongoDB 3.4. For older versions, you would need to copy the `oplogDump/local/oplog.rs.bson` to the root of the dump directory to a file named `oplog.bson`, e.g. `oplogDump/oplog.bson` and remove the `oplogFile` parameter from the example command above.

After Step 4, if your oplog goes back to the beginning of time and you stop the oplog replay at the right time, hopefully you should see your data at the point just before the `dropDatabase` command was executed.

Comment: Thank you! I have successfully restored my database

Comment: I found you also need to grant additional permissions, as none of the built in roles can manipulate the op log. This post has a good guide on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208028/mongodb-applyops-not-authorized-on-admin-to-execute-command. I also found that if I provided `oplogDump` as a parameter it tried to load oplog.rs.bson twice. I had to make an empty directory and point to that instead.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to get it restored