# MongoDB : applyOps: not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore, mongodb-oplog

A Very Good Day,

I have the user in the mongodb like below who has the superuser privileges (I confirmed the role setting using `show users` command)

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.mongoadmin",
    "user" : "mongoadmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

when I try to restore the oplog using the mongorestore, I get the error :

**Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: not authorized on admin to execute command** { applyOps: [ { ts: Timestamp(1552828309, 1), h: 4632811839329880092, v: 2, op: "c", ns: "admin.$cmd", o: { create: "system.keys", idIndex: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "*id*", ns: "admin.system.keys" } }, o2: {} } ], $db: "admin" }

```
mongorestore -u admin -p password --authenticationDatabase=admin --oplogFile 0000000000_0_oplog.bson  --oplogReplay --oplogLimit=1552828432 --dir='/oplog/temp'
2019-03-17T13:47:36.945+0000    preparing collections to restore from
2019-03-17T13:47:36.945+0000    replaying oplog
2019-03-17T13:47:36.962+0000    Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: not authorized on admin to execute command { applyOps: [ { ts: Timestamp(1552828309, 1), h: 4632811839329880092, v: 2, op: "c", ns: "admin.$cmd", o: { create: "system.keys", idIndex: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.keys" } }, o2: {} } ], $db: "admin" }
```

**NOTE** : I specified the oploglimit (--oplogLimit=1552828432) with the last value I got from the bsondump 
Is this correct? Or Am I missing anything?

(i.e)

```
{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1552828432,"i":79}},"t":{"$numberLong":"1"},"h":{"$numberLong":"-2072015676601300967"},"v":2,"op":"i","ns":"inventory.hari","ui":{"$binary":"avdlGH8AS1eBPXRytlO1Yg==","$type":"04"},"wall":{"$date":"2019-03-17T13:13:52.139Z"},"o":{"_id":"79","name":"Hari","role":"Developer","isEmployee":true}}
{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1552828432,"i":80}},"t":{"$numberLong":"1"},"h":{"$numberLong":"-6279494628130059002"},"v":2,"op":"u","ns":"inventory.hari","ui":{"$binary":"avdlGH8AS1eBPXRytlO1Yg==","$type":"04"},"o2":{"_id":"79"},"wall":{"$date":"2019-03-17T13:13:52.139Z"},"o":{"_id":"79","name":"WD_Userjava.util.Random@9a7504c","role":"Developer","isEmployee":true}}
```

Anyhelp is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
use admin

db.createRole(
   {
     role: "interalUseOnlyOplogRestore",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { anyResource: true }, actions: [ "anyAction" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)

db.createUser({
  user: "root",
  pwd: "password",
  roles: [
    {role: "root", db: "admin"},"__system","interalUseOnlyOplogRestore","backup"
  ]
})
```

Better though to reduce the privileges to something like below.

```
db.createUser({
  user: "root2",
  pwd: "password",
  roles: [
    "interalUseOnlyOplogRestore"
  ]
})
```

After this you can run the restore command

```
mongorestore --port 27017 --oplogReplay oplogRestore --authenticationDatabase admin -u root2 -p password
```